# Grouped multiplication of matrices with unequal dimensions

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to determine how I can do the following:

I have 2 matrices, each row is a date and each column is a number. The second matrix is much longer than the first.  I want to create a function that will multiply the first row (say its a January number) by the first 4 rows of second matrix (which are all January numbers as well).  So, I'm looking for 4 results.  Then I want to move to the second row of the first matrix (February number) and multiply it by the 4 February numbers from the second matrix.  Eventually, I am hoping to get to the code that will multiply the first by the second if the month and years match.

First Matrix

```
Jan 2007        143.75
Feb 2007        140.93
```

Second Matrix

```
2007-01-05         12.14
2007-01-12         10.15
2007-01-19         10.40
2007-01-26         11.13
2007-02-02         10.08
2007-02-09         11.10
2007-02-16         10.02
2007-02-23         10.58
```

Comment: Are the dates on the left the row names? Or is that it's own column?  `dput`s of these would be best so we can know the exact structure of the data sets.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those are both matrices, and that the dates on the left are the row names, you can try something along these lines.  Here we match the months of the row names of two matrices and use it to create a vector for the calculation.

```
idx <- match(format(as.Date(rownames(m2)), "%b"), sub(" .*", "", rownames(m1)))
m2 * m1[idx]
#                [,1]
# 2007-01-05 1745.125
# 2007-01-12 1459.062
# 2007-01-19 1495.000
# 2007-01-26 1599.938
# 2007-02-02 1420.574
# 2007-02-09 1564.323
# 2007-02-16 1412.119
# 2007-02-23 1491.039
```

**Data:**

```
m1 <- structure(c(143.75, 140.93), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Jan 2007", "Feb 2007"), NULL))
m2 <- structure(c(12.14, 10.15, 10.4, 11.13, 10.08, 11.1, 10.02, 10.58
), .Dim = c(8L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("2007-01-05", "2007-01-12", 
"2007-01-19", "2007-01-26", "2007-02-02", "2007-02-09", "2007-02-16", 
"2007-02-23"), NULL))
```

**Note:** You haven't given us much information in your post, like whether or not you are doing this for multiple years, whether the dates are the row names or columns, etc.  If you are doing this for multiple years, then please post a more representative data example with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
row.names(m2) <- format(as.Date(row.names(m2)), '%b %Y')
transform(merge(m1, m2, by = "row.names"), new = V1.x * V1.y)
#  Row.names   V1.x  V1.y      new
#1  Feb 2007 140.93 10.08 1420.574
#2  Feb 2007 140.93 11.10 1564.323
#3  Feb 2007 140.93 10.02 1412.119
#4  Feb 2007 140.93 10.58 1491.039
#5  Jan 2007 143.75 12.14 1745.125
#6  Jan 2007 143.75 10.15 1459.062
#7  Jan 2007 143.75 10.40 1495.000
#8  Jan 2007 143.75 11.13 1599.938
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(143.75, 140.93), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), 
 .Dimnames = list(
   c("Jan 2007", "Feb 2007"), NULL))
m2 <- structure(c(12.14, 10.15, 10.4, 11.13, 10.08, 11.1, 
    10.02, 10.58), .Dim = c(8L, 1L), 
 .Dimnames = list(c("2007-01-05", "2007-01-12", 
 "2007-01-19", "2007-01-26", "2007-02-02", "2007-02-09", 
 "2007-02-16", "2007-02-23"), NULL))
```